# Proving that two variational problems are equivalent

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, calculus-of-variations, laplacian

Let $\Omega$ be an open set of finite measure. Let $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ be the first Dirichlet eigenvalue for the Laplace operator, i.e.
$$- \Delta u = \lambda_1(\Omega) u, \ \  \ \ \ \text{in} \  \Omega$$
$$u = 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega  $$
In variational terms
$$\lambda_1(\Omega) = \min_{u \in H^1_0(\Omega)} {\frac{\int_{\Omega}{ ||\nabla u || ^2 dx}}{\int_{\Omega}{||u||^2 dx}}}$$

Consider the problem:
$$\text{min} \{ \lambda_1(\Omega) : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N, \text{Vol}(\Omega) = m \}$$
i.e. among all measurable open sets of the volume $m$ we find one that minimizes the first eigenvalue.

By Faber-Krahn inequality it is known that the solution to the above problem is the ball of volume $m$.

Let also
$$\text{min} \{\lambda_1(\Omega) + C \ \text{Vol}(\Omega) : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \}$$

be a free boundary problem.

**Proposition**
There exists $C > 0$ such that the problems above are equivalent

(equivalence means the following: if the solution to the first problem exists and unique, then the latter is the unique solution to the second problem and vice versa)

How i can check that?

My progress:

(1) First note that the solution to the first problem exists due to the inequality
$$\lambda_1(\Omega) \geq \frac{C}{\text{Vol}(\Omega) ^ {\frac{2}{N}}}$$

(This follows from Sobolev inequality)

(2) The natural idea: given $m := \text{Vol}(\Omega)$ one should find $C > 0$ such that the minimum in the second problem is attained at the argmin of the first and vice versa. The latter means that it would be nice to find a kind of relation of the form: $f(m) = g(C)$, where $f, g$ are sufficiently nice functions.

**The questions are**:

- How can i check the equivalence?
- subquestion: how i can approach the second problem from the scratch, i.e. to find the minimum using some variational arguments?
  It sound that it's ok to consider a sort of "dilating variation", e.g., for 
  $$J(\Omega) = \lambda_1(\Omega) + |C| \text{Vol}(\Omega)$$
  consider 
  $$J_t(\Omega) = \lambda_1(t \Omega) + |C| \text{Vol}(t \Omega) = \frac{\lambda_1(\Omega)}{t^2} + C t^{n} \text{Vol}(\Omega)$$